# jquery : Select last element which content is

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In jquery, how to select the last `<li>` containing a `bar` string in the following HTML :

```
<ul>
    <li>bar</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>bar</li> <!-- I want to select this one -->
    <li>foo</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: To the downvoters, you should say why. I agree, a little googling and reading about jQuery contains and last selecting might have helped but some people don't know how to get that far. @lapin, next time try to show what you have tried to avoid downvotes.

Comment: @reditor thank you for your comment. I just wanted to be straightforward to allow faster reading because I know how painful it is to try to understand messy questions to help people.

Comment: Is the html fixed one? or changes dynamically? btw, add class and make life easier. :)

Comment: I knew there should have some ways to achieve it in a clever way with jquery but simply looking for those keywords in google and stackoverflow didn't showed relevant answers (too many CSS last-child related questions). I didn't find any duplicate either that's why I thought It worthed to ask.

Comment: @Mr_Green It's dynamic content. Actualy bar and foo are user generated content and it may take any value. Do you still think that using class would have made things easier ? if yes, how ? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

```js
// :contains(bar) would match 'bar', 'barbell' and 'rebar':
$('li:contains(bar)').last().css('color','red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>bar</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>bar</li> <!-- I want to select this one -->
    <li>foo</li>
</ul>
```

Though bear in mind that `:contains()` is *not precise*:

```js
// :contains(bar) would match 'bar', 'barbell' and 'rebar':
$('li:contains(bar)').last().css('color','red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>bar</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>bar</li> <!-- I want to select this one -->
    <li>barbell</li>
</ul>
```

Or:

```js
$('li').filter(function () {
    // this retains only those <li> elements whose text is exactly equal to 'bar':
    return $(this).text() === 'bar';
// selects the last of the elements from the collection:
}).last().css('color','red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>bar</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>bar</li> <!-- I want to select this one -->
    <li>foo</li>
</ul>
```

References:

- [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/).

Comment: Thank you for your very fast and complete answer ! That worked perfectly.

Comment: You're very welcome indeed; I'm glad to have helped! :)

Answer (score 3):

use **[contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)** and **[last()](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)** selector in jquery

```
$( "ul li:contains('bar'):last" ).css("color","red");
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xtz111q3/4/)**

Comment: Thank your for your answer. it works just fine. I chose the other one for it was a little bit faster.

Comment: @lapin Ok .Anyway i am really happy to help you :)